# getting json responce from twitter api using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, twitter

```
function GetTweets(){
        var url ='https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?count=2&callback=http://bidashboardlocal.com&screen_name=twitterapi&oauth_consumer_key=aExUgXGwG357VBdiPxiyg9uc6&oauth_nonce=e926bc4a1387ba2b90cc9c314e9718c9&oauth_signature=p5FW6On9cn8IlC1ATJW2e9OoIE0%3D&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1449567954&oauth_token=3717206714-GmBMClz8ULTV8JibTiUeQ2923tyn9H6e9hLRjf0&oauth_version=1.0';
        $.getJSON(url, function(data){
            alert(data);
            $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                $("#Test").append("<li>" 
                                        + item.text.linkify() 
                                        + " <span class='created_at'>" 
                                        + relative_time(item.created_at) 
                                        + " via " 
                                        + item.source
                                        + "</span></li>");
            });
        });

    }
```

i am trying to get my latest tweet using this code 
when i try to test the url in the browser it returns a json file inside it i can read the json 
how can i get the return json in the file by using jquery ??
any suggestions ?

Comment: in your code, `data` should contain the JSON content

Comment: yes but when i execute this function it give me error 401 : unauthorized :/
but when i execute the url inside the browser it return the file 
i don't understand the problem

Answer (score 0):

I think your API-Authentication are Bad.
check the API-Url and try again. Maybe you create a new one.

Comment: why it return the json file if i put the url in the browser than ?

Comment: of course you will because you need to be sign id to my account first

Comment: But you will show the data the users of you website... so the data must be public .. or i am wrong?

Comment: i am not getting the data , my problem is that i am not getting the data in the first place

Comment: When you mean i need your Twitter Session to get the data than is that problem that getJSON do not provide cookies and Twitter also do not allow that